# spring mybatis how to build different condition operator

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am using spring boot and mybatis, my code looks like:

```
class StudentController {
....
List<Student> listStudent(Student student, Pageable pageable) {
    return this.studentService.listStudent(student, pageable)
}

}

class StudentService {
....
List<Student> listStudent(Student student, Pageable pageable) {
    return this.studentDao.listStudent(student, pageable)
}

}

class StudentDao {
    List<Student> listStudent(Student student, Pageable pageable);
}
```

the sql xml file looks like:

```
<select id="listStudent" resultType="student">
    select * from student
    <where>
        <if test="student.age != null">age = #{student.age}</if>
    </where>
</select>
```

client may list student via `spring controller` or call `studentService.listStudent` from java code.

the code only can build the `equal` condition operator sql, e.g. `select * from student where age = 10`.

how can I build different conditions operator?
Since sometimes client may want to query student whose `age > 10` or `age < 10` or `age between 10 and 12` or other condition operator.

Comment: A simple solution is to create a parameter object that holds 'operator' and 'values'. Your statement would look something like : `<if test="ageOp == 'eq'">age = #{ageVal}</if><if test="ageOp == 'btwn'">age between #{ageVal} and #{ageVal2}</if><if ...`. If your project has many of those statements, I would suggest taking a look at [mybatis-dynamic-sql](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql) that saves you from writing the boilerplates.

Comment: @ave thanks for your tip. From website, it seems that mybatis-dynamic-sql only support java code, but I have to use xml file to write sql.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add two properties to the Student class, instead of a single age property:

```java
Integer minAge,
Integer maxAge
```

That way to perform an equals query you set them to the same value, and to perform a range query, you set one or both to a value.

```xml
<select id="listStudent" resultType="student">
    select * from student
    <where>
        <if test="student.minAge != null">age > #{student.minAge} </if>
        <if test="student.minAge != null && student.maxAge != null"> AND </if>
        <if test="student.maxAge != null">age < #{student.maxAge} </if>
    </where>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, I thought of this approach, but I have no idea it's elegant or not.